# Re-Run testng failed xml file to excute failed test cases

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

How do i code to re-run testng-failed.xml after making some corrections in code?

Please help.

Also, please guide a source from which i can understand testng.xml file.

i tried reading the files and develop some understanding but not able to edit it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just run an .xml file you need using IDE(with plugin) or add it to pom.xml if you use Maven.
All documentation about testng.xml you can find [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html)